# Javascript function to change put border around selected divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a Javascript function that is part of web game I'm creating. It is supposed to act as the speed selector for an object in the game. Selecting the `div` that says "slow" is supposed to change the object's speed to slow, and so forth. When the page is loaded, the "med" div is selected. For now, I just want to figure out why my attempt at putting a border around the currently selected speed `div` is not working. The code below is, hopefully, self-explanatory. (Here's a link to the game, if that helps: http://jaminweb.com/snake_TEST_PHP.php)

I'm not getting any errors in my Javascript console and I've tested (using an `alert(...)`) to make sure the onlick functions are being called for each of the 3 divs when I click on them.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Relevant pieces of code:

```
    function speedController(slowButtonID, medButtonID, fastButtonID, sg)
    {
    /*
         slowButtonID, medButtonID, fastButtonID: IDs of the buttons for slow, medium and fast, respectively

         sg: Snake game object
    */

        this.spdMap = {"slow" : [slowButtonID, 200], "med" : [medButtonID, 100], "fast" : [fastButtonID , 50]};

        this.curSpd = "med";

        this.changeSpeed = function(newSpd)
        {
        /*
            newSpd: one of "slow", "med" or "fast"
        */
            /* Do nothing if selecting same speed as current */
            if (newSpd == this.curSpd)
                return;

            /* Else, remove border from currently selected speed button 
               and add border to newly selected speed button, then 
               change the speed of the snake's mover.
            */
            $("#"+this.spdMap[this.curSpd[0]]).css("border: 0px;");
            $("#"+this.spdMap[newSpd[0]]).css("border: 4px solid #3D4048;");
            sg.mover = setInterval(sg.move(), this.spdMap[newSpd[1]]);
        }
    }
```

---

```
        <div id="snakeSpdDiv">
            <p><b>Speed:</b></p>
            <div class="snakeSpdBtn" id="snakeSpdSlow">Slow</div>
            <div class="snakeSpdBtn" id="snakeSpdMed" style="border: 4px solid #3D4048;">Med</div>
            <div class="snakeSpdBtn" id="snakeSpdFast" onlick=>Fast</div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var sc = new speedController("snakeSpdSlow", "snakeSpdMed", "snakeSpdFast", s);
                $("#snakeSpdSlow").click(function()
                { 
                    sc.changeSpeed("slow");
                });
                $("#snakeSpdMed").click(function() 
                { 
                    sc.changeSpeed("med"); 
                });
                $("#snakeSpdFast").click(function()
                { 
                    sc.changeSpeed("fast"); 
                });
            </script>
        </div>
```

Comment: The proper syntax for `.css()` is `.css("border", "4px solid #3D4048")`. http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this part:

```
$("#"+this.spdMap[this.curSpd[0]]).css("border: 0px;");
$("#"+this.spdMap[newSpd[0]]).css("border: 4px solid #3D4048;");
```

It should be:

```
$("#"+this.spdMap[this.curSpd][0]).css("border", "0px");
$("#"+this.spdMap[newSpd][0]).css("border", "4px solid #3D4048");
```

Also, you need to change `this.curSpd` with `newSpd` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using your `curSpd`/`newSpd` variables correctly. They should be:

```
$("#"+this.spdMap[this.curSpd]).css("border", "0px");
$("#"+this.spdMap[newSpd]).css("border", "4px solid #3D4048");
```

Also, as imtheman pointed out, your `css` call needs to be fixed.

Comment: You're on the right track, but this is also incorrect because `this.spdMap[this.curSpd]` and `this.spdMap[newSpd]` are arrays.

Comment: @imtheman Haha, you're right, but I tested my code and it works. Seems that the string resolves to `"#snakeSpdMed,200"` which also selects the correct element!

Comment: Oh interesting. I guess that makes sense though, as the JQuery selector is comma delimited.